# debugging with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I want to compile a C file with gcc, and my question is this: Is it possible when we have a mistake in our code  (for example, forgetting a semicolon) for gcc to show us the source code containing the error(s)?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you have a syntax error, your code won't compile (you would have discovered this if you had tried it!).  Of course, there are many ways to make mistakes that don't result in syntax errors.

Comment: How I interpreted your question: You want to compile a C program with potential errors. Why not compile it and see what happens? EDIT: just so you know, gcc gives the line where the error is located.

Comment: I interpreted the question differently @itdoesntwork … as more of, “can I see the offending code…”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` will print out the (approximate) line and position where the error occurred, and in which file.

But, no, `gcc` doesn't repeat your code; you'll have to open the file, and go to that line.

Typically, your Integrated Development Environment, however, will allow you to click on the error reference in the `gcc` output, and take you directly to that line. This is true of (at least) Eclipse, Anjuta, and Emacs.

(And always use `-Wextra`)

Comment: +1 for `-Wextra`. But if you are dealing with legacy code, you'll likely need to suppress some warnings via `-Wno-sign-compare`.  Also, adding `-Wshadow` has saved me from many a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The format of `gcc` diagnostics is a line number and a diagnostic message. The offending code is not displayed.

If you want more expressive diagnostics you can try the `clang` compiler. The format of `clang` diagnostics is a line number, a column number, the diagnostic message and the paste of the offending code with some markups to shows where the issue is.

For example, given this code with a missing semi-colon after the printf statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 42;

    printf("%d\n", a)

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the difference of the diagnostic messages between `gcc` and `clang`:

```
$ gcc -Wall tst.c
tst.c: In function ‘main’:
tst.c:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
$ clang -Wall tst.c
tst.c:7:22: error: expected ';' after expression
    printf("%d\n", a)
                     ^
                     ;
1 diagnostic generated.
$
```